# I need to display an image stored in my gallery through my SQL Query on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is what helps me to display radio buttons on the website. The radio buttons are now in text format. The images are stored in a folder on my server. $sep_row['av_image'] displays the name of the image. but i want to display this in png format.

Thank you for the help in advance.

```
$i=1;
$avaQuery ="SELECT * FROM dd_ava_mst ORDER BY av_code_name";
$seldata_cat = $obj->selectQuery($avaQuery);
if($q==2)
                {
                    $output .= '<b style="color: #000000;">Availability:</b>';
                    $output .= "<table  width=\"400\"  border=\"0\" >\n"; //open table tag
                    while($sep_row = mysql_fetch_array($seldata_cat)){

                        $checked = '';
                        if(in_array($sep_row['av_id'], $fdiva_cat_sub_array)){
                            $checked = 'checked="checked"';
                        }
                            if($i==1)
                            {
                            $output .= "<tr class='yl_tb'>";
                            }

                            $output .= "<td class='yl_tb' >";
                            $output .= '<input '.$checked.' type="radio"  name="fav_id[]" value="'.$sep_row['av_id'].'" />'.$sep_row['av_image']; 
                            $output .= "</td>\n"; 
                            if($i==3)
                            {
                            $output .= "</tr>";
                                    $i=0;
                            }
                         $i++;          
                    }
                    $output .= "</table>\n"; 
                }
```

This is the output now

Availability:
Green.png   Orange.png  Orange.png
red.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a image element and the use `$sep_row['av_image']` as the `img source`

here is the

```
$output .= '<input '.$checked.' type="radio"  name="fav_id[]" value="'.$sep_row['av_id'].'" /> <img src="./the foldername/'.$sep_row['av_image']. '" />';
```

make sure `./the foldername/` is your image directory.

Comment: Hi Avik Thank you for the solution, worked like a charm, i have been trying to do this for the past couple of hours. Appreciate the help a lot.